# Printing is suspended if no line feed is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I have worked 2 years with Python 2.7 and had not so much trouble as I with working a couple om months with Python 3.7! Here's is one of them, a very annoying one:

```
import msvcrt

print("Press any key: ", end="")
c = msvcrt.getch()
# Whatever ...
```

When running the above code, the printing of the prompt is suspended until a (non status) key is pressed, at which time the message is displayed (followed by whatever follows). This of course does not happen with Python 2.

Now, if the message is preceded with a line feed,

```
print("\nPress any key: ", end="")
```

the printing is executed before the execution of 'getch()', i.e. as expected!

What's the deal here? Is there a way to handle this problem w/o adding extra line feeds?

Comment: It works fine for me using Windows 10 and the Cygwin terminal. When I run it in `cmd.exe` and add a `print(c)` line afterward, it is blank until I press a key, then it prints `Press any key: ` and the key I pressed (as a bytestring). Powershell 7 does the same thing.

Comment: If your print isn't showing immediately, try adding the `flush=True` argument.

Comment: @MattDMo, I don't know what Cygwin platform is, but I understand that in MS DOS (cmd.exe), the same problem happens to you too, right?

Comment: @kehlwood, it works! Thank you very much.